# Coq proof that the Selection monad is an applicative and a monad

Tags: functor, coq, applicative, theorem-proving

I am pretty new to coq and I have so far managed to only prove things that are I can also prove by hand. So when I came across the Selection monad and decided to implement it in haskell, I thought it would be a good excercise but I got stuck. Could someone provide an example of a proof in coq that the selection monad is an applicative and a monad? Here is a haskell implementation of the functor.

```
newtype Sel r a = Sel { runSel :: (a -> r) -> a }

instance Functor (Sel r) where
  fmap ab (Sel ara) = Sel (ab . ara . (. ab))
```

Extra thanks if you can also also prove the monad laws.

EDIT: Here is my proof that the functor exists:

```
Definition sel (R A : Type) := (A -> R) -> A.

Theorem functor_exists : forall (R A B : Type),
    (A -> B) -> sel R A -> sel R B.
  intros R A B. unfold sel. intros AB ARA BR.
  apply AB. apply ARA. intro. apply BR. apply AB. exact X.
  Qed.
```

Comment: When I first started to use Coq, I reimplemented the definitions and lemmas from this ["tutorial"](https://pdp7.org/blog/2011/01/the-maybe-monad-in-coq/) and then switched to other (more interesting) monads.

Comment: I have done those but I can't seem to do much beyond that. I thought this one would be quite simple to a seasoned coq-ist, that's why I posted, but I might be wrong.

Comment: But then I guess that you can provide the Coq code, so that one can see the specific case where you get stuck?

Comment: I edited my post with my proof that the functor exists. I am just running in circles about the applicative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use tactics because it's Coq: you can use it as a programming language in a way that is fairly similar to Haskell.

First, because `R` is going to be a variable present all the time in this section, we can make the notations a bit lighter by mentioning it once and for all:

```
Section SelMon.
Variable (R : Type).
```

We can then replicate your definition of `sel` (without the `R` variable because it's already in context). And write `fmap` as a nice definition rather than a proof using tactics:

```
Definition sel (A : Type) := (A -> R) -> A.

Definition fmap {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) (s : sel A) : sel B :=
  fun br => f (s (fun a => br (f a))).
```

The next step to prove that you have an applicative is to provide a `pure` method. Well it's easy enough: we can use a constant function.

```
Definition pure {A : Type} (a : A) : sel A :=
  fun _ => a.
```

Then it gets a bit hairy. I'd advise you to start with `join` and then derive `bind` (and `app` from it) using the canonical constructions:

```
Definition join {A : Type} (ssa : sel (sel A)) : sel A.
Admitted.

Definition bind {A B : Type} (sa : sel A) (asb : A -> sel B) : sel B.
Admitted.

Definition app {A B : Type} (sab : sel (A -> B)) (sa : sel A) : sel B.
Admitted.
```

Once you're done with these, you can close the section and `R` will be added as a parameter to all of your definitions.

```
End SelMon.
```

Comment: Interesting. many features of coq I didn't know about so thanks. How hard do you think it would be to also prove the relevant laws?

Comment: The relevant laws (interpreted in a strict sense) are probably going to be unprovable because `sel A` is a function space. If you're willing to assume functional extensionality and you already know a pen and paper proof, it shouldn't be too awful.

Comment: You are right, thank you. For future reference the notes at the end of chapter 1 of the [HoTT book](https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-online-1075-g3c53219.pdf) cleared the whole issue up for me.